# How to print output of players names using JS & HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hey so I am new to using JS and HTML and still practicing the language, I am trying to print out the user name of both players but without using alert. I want to print the player's names and later going to change it up using CSS but having trouble with the simplest way of printing user inputs I have this so far and was wondering why it is not working, any help will be appreciated.

```js
 function welcome(){
        var first = document.getElementById("FirstName").value; 
        var last = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
        var Print_name = "Welcome " + first +" "+ last;
        console.log(Print_name);
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Print Names</title>
      </head>
  <body>
<form method="get">

    <label for="Player1Name">Player 1 Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Player1Name" name="player1Name" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <label for="Player2Name">Player 2 Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Player2Name" name="player2Name" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">


</form>
<script>
     /*javascript code here*/
    
  </script>

  </body>
  
  
  
</html>
```

Comment: There's no element with the id "FirstName" or "LastName".  The inputs you have are Player1Name and Player2Name.  You should see the error "can't access property "value", document.getElementById(...) is null" in console.

Answer (score 0):

You should find an HTML element (with id="Player1Name") and (with id="Player2Name").

Try it code in HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" onclick="welcome()">
```

Try it code in JavaScript

```
 function welcome(){
    var first = document.getElementById("Player1Name").value; 
    var last = document.getElementById("Player2Name").value;
    var Print_name = "Welcome " + first +" "+ last;
    alert(Print_name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your document.getElementById is referencing the wrong Id.

So if you text field is defined as

```
<input type="text" **id="Player1Name"** name="player1Name" placeholder="Name">
```

Then what you should be doing is document.getElementById("**Player1Name**").value

The same goes with the Player2Name field.